# Expressing a matrix as an expansion of its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This shouldn't be too difficult but I can't find a satisfactory proof.

> Show that a real, symmetric matrix $A$ with dimensions $D \times D$ satisfying the eigenvector
>   equation $Au_{i} = \lambda u_{i}$ can be expressed as an expansion of
>   its eigenvalues in the following way:
>
> $$A = \sum_{i=1}^{D}\lambda_{i}u_{i}u_{i}^{T}$$ and similarly, the
>   inverse $A^{-1}$ can be expressed as
>
> $$A^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{D}\frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}u_{i}u_{i}^{T}$$

I suppose this is an alternative form of eigendecomposition. I know this can be proved using $AU = U\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix and $U$ an orthogonal matrix, but it's a somewhat tedious procedure.

An additional question: Do I need to assume a real, symmetric matrix?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Symmetry is to guarantee that the eigenvalues are real, and consequently eigenvectors of different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

Comment: Robert, did you get this question from the Machine Learning book from Christopher Bishop? :) In any case, what I still don't understand is how
$$
\sum_{k}{(\lambda_{k}u_{k}^{T}x)u_{k}} = \sum_{k}{\lambda_{k}u_{k}u_{k}^{T}x}
$$ I worked it out by manually expanding 2x1 $u$ and $x$ vectors. But, I can't figure out the general proof. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it was from Bishop's book. By the way, you should have added this as a comment, not as another answer. You can change the order of the terms there because you're dealing with values, not with matrices. Therefore, there are no issues with the ordering of terms.

Comment: @Phoeniyx this is Exercise 2.19 of the Christopher Bishop's book

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proof using $AU = U\Lambda$ is not tedious. Since the $U$ is orthogonal, you have $U^{-1} = U^T$, so $A = U \Lambda U^T$.
Then
$$Ax = U \Lambda U^T x = U \Lambda \begin{bmatrix} u_1^T x \\ \vdots \\ u_n^T x \end{bmatrix} = U  \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 u_1^T x \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n u_n^T x \end{bmatrix} = \sum_k (\lambda_k u_k^T x) u_k = \sum_k \lambda_k u_k u_k^T x = (\sum_k \lambda_k u_k u_k^T)x$$

Hence $A=\sum_k \lambda_k u_k u_k^T$.

Since $AU = U\Lambda$, inverting both sides gives $U^T A^{-1} = \Lambda^{-1} U^T$, and hence $A^{-1} = U\Lambda^{-1} U^T$. Applying the above result to $A^{-1}$, noting that $\Lambda^{-1}$ is just the diagonal matrix of the inverses of the diagonal elements of $\Lambda$, we have $A^{-1} = \sum_k \frac{1}{\lambda_k} u_k u_k^T$.

To address your other question, the same result holds for Hermitian matrices ($A^* = A$), with the proviso that the $U$ will be unitary rather than orthogonal (ie, may be complex).

A normal matrix ($A A^* = A^* A$) can also be expressed as above, except the eigenvalues may be complex (and eigenvectors, of course)

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $ is real, but not symmetric, but does not have a basis of eigenvectors (hence it cannot be expressed as above).

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & i \\ i & 0 \end{bmatrix} $ is symmetric but not real (it is normal). It can be unitarily diagonalized, but the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are complex.

Comment: Excellent answer. In the first part, you're using partitioned matrices, right? I'm not too comfortable using them, so I had to expand the products. By the way, do you really need $x$ in $Ax$? In the sum $\sum_{k} (\lambda_{k}u_{k}^{T}x)u_{k}$, why did you multiply $u_{k}$ on the right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by partitioned matrices in this context. Yes, you need the $x$; the point of the $x$ was so that the terms $(\lambda u_k^T x) u_k$ could be written as $(\lambda u_k u_k^T) x$. When you have a product $By$ this is equal to $\sum_k y_k b_k$, where $b_k$ is the $k$th column of $B$, and $y_k$ is the $k$th component of $y$, a scalar. This is why the $u_k$ are on the right.

Comment: Maybe you know them as block matrices, e.g. $U^{T}$ contains rows with eigenvectors of $A$, but instead of writing every vector, we just use $\begin{bmatrix} u_1^T \\ \vdots \\ u_n^T \end{bmatrix}$. Then in your third step you have $[u_{1} \cdots u_{n}]$ where each $u_{i}$ is a column vector, so you multiply that $1XN$ matrix by a $NX1$ matrix.

Comment: Well, they are $n \times n$, but arranged as $n$ columns or rows as the case may be. The proof is basically just multiplying the matrices out in a convenient format.

Comment: Now that I have read your edit, your procedure makes perfect sense. Last thing, where do I find more information about the representation $AU = U\Lambda$ of the eigenvector equation?

Comment: I would guess any matrix text will have a discussion about symmetric matrices. However, the idea is straightforward. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $A$ maps $\operatorname{sp} \{v \}$ into $\operatorname{sp} \{v \}$ (all matrices do). However, since $A$ is symmetric, $A$ maps $\{v\}^\bot$ into $\{v\}^\bot$, and so choosing $v$ and a basis of $\{v\}^\bot$ partially diagonalizes $A$. Then you repeat the process with the smaller part of $A$. The resulting eigenvectors are orthogonal by design.

Comment: Copper.hat, this is such a superb answer. I was looking for the answer to this question for a whole day on Google!

Comment: @Phoeniyx: Glad it helped!

Comment: I didn't understand what is `x`? Is it an arbitrary real number, a vector or a matrix? I also didn't understand the explanation by @copper.hat on why `x` is needed

Comment: Also, in $ \sum_k (\lambda_k u_k^T x) u_k $, $u_k^T \in \mathcal{R}^{1 \times D}$, so it's a row vector, while $u_k \in \mathcal{R}^{D \times 1}$ is a column vector, so the result is a number; while in the next term, $u_k u_k^T$ should be a matrix, no?

Comment: @raffamaiden: $x$ is an arbitrary vector in the domain of $A$. It is fairly standard notation ($Ax$). I don't know what you are asking in your last comment. A scalar times a vector is still a vector.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the explanation. So $x \in \mathcal{R}^D$, right? I think I have understood the second part of my question. In the proof you wrote $= \sum_k (\lambda_k u_k^T x) u_k = \sum_k \lambda_k u_k u_k^T x$. The left hand side is a vector: $u_k^T x$ is a scalar, multiplied by a vector is a vector. While the RHS $u_k u_k^T$ is a matrix, dot product by a vector is a vector

Answer (score 2):

The official solution (from the Tutor's edition of the solutions manual) is as follows (the matrix is called $\Sigma$ instead of $A$):

> We can rewrite the r.h.s. of (2.48) in matrix form as  $$\sum_{i=1}^D \lambda_i \mathbf{u}_i \mathbf{u}_i^T = \mathbf{U} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{U}^T = \mathbf{M}$$
>
> where $\mathbf{U}$ is a $D \times D$ matrix with the eigenvectors
>   $\mathbf{u}_1, \dots, \mathbf{u}_D$ as its columns and
>   $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues
>   $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_D$ along its diagonal.
>
> Thus we have
>
> $$ \mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{U} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{\Lambda}$$
>
> However, from (2.45)-(2.47), we also have that
>
> $$ \mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{U} \mathbf{\Lambda} = \mathbf{\Lambda}$$
>
> and so $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{\Lambda}$ and (2.48) holds.
>
> Moreover, since $\mathbf{U}$ is orthonormal, $\mathbf{U}^{-1} = \mathbf{U}^T$ and so:
>
> $$ \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} = (\mathbf{U} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{U}^T)^{-1} =  (\mathbf{U}^T)^{-1} \mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1} \mathbf{U}^{-1} = \mathbf{U} \mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1} \mathbf{U}^T = \sum_{i=1}^D \dfrac{1}{\lambda_i} \mathbf{u}_i \mathbf{u}_i^T $$

Where (2.45) is

> $$  \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{u}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{u}_i $$

So that $ \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{U} = \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{U} $ is the eigenvector equation

Answer (score 1):

A nearly-trivial proof somewhat similar to copper.hat's is the following.

1. Two matrices are identical if they are identical on a basis.
2. Since the eigenvectors $\{u_i\}$ form an orthonormal basis (after normalization if needed), we only need verify the eigenvector expansion $A = \sum_{i=1}^{D}\lambda_{i}u_{i}u_{i}^{T}$ on the eigenvectors.
3. $(\sum_{i=1}^{D}\lambda_{i}u_{i}u_{i}^{T})u_j = \sum_{i=1}^{D}\lambda_{i}u_{i}(u_{i}^{T}u_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{D}\lambda_{i}u_{i}\delta_{ij} =  \lambda_{j}u_{j}$ because the eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis.
4. Because $u_j$ is an eigenvector this equals $Au_j$//

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).