# Can any diagonalizable matrix be expressed as a sum of its eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have diagonalizable $A = V \Lambda V^{-1}$ where the columns of $V$ are the right eigenvectors ($v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$), the rows of $V^{-1}$ are the left eigenvectors ($u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n$), and the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ are the corresponding eigenvalues ($\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$).

For real symmetric matrices I can write:

$$
A = V \Lambda V^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i u_i^T
$$

As for example discussed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/331836).

However as far as I can tell, I can do this with *any* diagonalisable matrix, right?

Here's my proof to sense check, but I'm wondering if I got it wrong somewhere:

$$
A = V \Lambda V^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n V \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} V^{-1}
$$

That is, rewrite the diagonal as the sum of $n$ matrices with one eigenvalue in each. Then for arbitrary $i$:

$$
 = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 v_2 \ldots v_n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u_1^T \\ u_2^T \\ \vdots \\ u_n^T\end{bmatrix} = \lambda_i \begin{bmatrix} 0 \ldots v_i \ldots 0 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ u_i^T \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \lambda_i \begin{bmatrix}
v_{i(1)}u_{i(1)} & v_{i(1)}u_{i(2)} & \ldots & v_{i(1)}u_{i(n)} \\
v_{i(2)}u_{i(1)} & \ldots & \ldots & v_{i(2)}u_{i(n)} \\
\vdots & \ldots & \ldots & \vdots \\
v_{i(n)}u_{i(1)} & \ldots & \ldots & v_{i(n)}u_{i(n)} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \lambda_i v_i u_i^T
$$

Therefore:

$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i u_i^T
$$

Have I made a mistake here? Whenever I've seen this expansion discussed, it is in the context of matrices with orthonormal eigenvectors, so not sure if I've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: No it isn't. The equality $A=V\Lambda V^{-1}$ is proved using the fact that $V$ is an orthogonal matrix. But if $V$ is orthogonal, then $A$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right. Since $V^{-1} A = \Lambda V^{-1}$, the rows of $V^{-1}$ are the left eigenvectors of $A$. So, as you showed you can do this expansion for any diagonalizable matrix.

Note that in the case of symmetric $A$, all right eigenvectors can be selected to be orthogonal to *each other* and right eigenvectors can be selected as the same as left eigenvectors (transposed of course), hence $V^{-1} = V^T$. But this is not the case in general. If $\lambda_i$ are distinct, all left eigenvectors are orthogonal to right eigenvectors with different eigenvalues. If $\lambda_i$ are not distinct such eigenvectors can be found.